# How to optimize recursive INSERT and SELECT DISTINCT mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables WData-Clean and WData. 
I import data in WData and it has a lot of duplicate records everytime. The data needs to be stacked overtime, so the duplicates cannot be removed. 
In WData-Clean I import all "unique" records in WData. A unique record in the example here is record that is different than all other similar records where certain fields may have the same values.

To do this I am using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `WData-clean` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`) 
SELECT DISTINCT `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`
FROM WData cr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `WData-clean` c
WHERE (cr.field1 = c.field1 AND cr.field2 = c.field2))
```

That used to work really well until WData accumulated over 2 million records, and this query is really struggling as it has to compare every proposal to each existing record in the source table.

How do I optimize performance of this query?

Answer (score 0):

When writing queries to normalize data, you should always use `GROUP BY`.

```
INSERT INTO `WData-clean` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`) 
(
    SELECT
        `field1`,
        `field2`,
        `field3`,
        `field4`,
        `field5`,
        `field6`
    FROM
        WData AS cr
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `WData-clean` AS c
        WHERE
            cr.field1 = c.field1
            AND cr.field2 = c.field2)
    )
    GROUP BY
        `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`
)
```

Also, it's outside the scope of this question (kinda), but I'd try to find a way to avoid the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. As *WData-clean* grows, that query will begin to take longer to match against.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 approaches:

1. In wdata_clean table create a unique index on all fields that need to be unique. Create a timestamp field in wdata table that records when the record was last changed. Also store the timestamp when you last refreshed wdata_clean. Then use `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT ...` whith a where criteria that selects those records from wdata that were modified since you last updated wdata_clean. Finally, update the timestamp of the last sync.
2. Create a timestamp field in wdata table and a varchar field in both tables. Also store the timestamp of last sync of the data. In the varchar field calculate the hash of all fields that must be unique (for example sha1). In the `insert ... select ...` do a left join on wdata_clean on the hash field with is null:

   `insert into wdata_clean
   select * from wdata left join wdata_clean on wdata.hashfield=wdata_clean.hashfield where wdata_clean.hashfield is null and wdata.timestampfield>'timestamp of last sync'`

Create composite index on the hash and timestamp fields in wdata and on the hash field in wdata_clean table.

3. Create a hash field in wdata_clean as described in the 2nd point and add a unique index on it. Add insert / update / delete triggers to wdata. In the triggers calculate the hash of the fields to be unique and do an `insert ignore ...` into the wdata_cleaned table.

Answer (score 0):

You current query is in effect performing the sub query once for every row on WData (as the sub query depends on the row from WData).

If you have indexes on the fields I would do a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN based on the fields that potentially match, and check in the WHERE clause that no matching row was found:-

```
INSERT INTO WData-clean (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) 
SELECT DISTINCT cr.field1, cr.field2, cr.field3, cr.field4, cr.field5, cr.field6
FROM WData cr
LEFT OUTER JOIN WData-clean c
ON cr.field1 = c.field1 
AND cr.field2 = c.field2
WHERE c.field1 IS NULL
```

(this example assumes c.field1 cannot legitimately have a NULL value - likely best to use the primary key from the WData-clean table to avoid this issue)